# open cv python drawing with the mouse

Tags: python, opencv

I keep getting an invalid syntax error with this. So, how can I resolve this and where can I find related documentation in the future.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

drawing = False # true if mouse is pressed
mode = True # if True, draw rectangle. Press 'm' to toggle to curve
ix,iy = -1,-1
class DessinerLigne:
def dessinerLigne(self):
    # Create a black image
    self.img=np.zeros((512,512,3),np.uint8)


def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global ix,iy,drawing,mode

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing = True
        ix,iy = x,y

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing == True:
            if mode == True:
                cv2.rectangle(img,(ix,iy),(x,y),(0,255,0),-1)
            else:
                cv2.circle(img,(x,y),5,(0,0,255),-1)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing = False
        if mode == True:
            cv2.rectangle(img,(ix,iy),(x,y),(0,255,0),-1)
        else:
            cv2.circle(img,(x,y),5,(0,0,255),-
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)

    cv2.imshow("Image", self.img)
    # If q is pressed then exit program
    self.k=cv2.waitKey(0)
    if self.k==ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__=="__main__":
DL=DessinerLigne()
DL.dessinerLigne()
```

Comment: What error were you receiving?

Comment: Please add the specific error and where it is located your code to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There clearly are multiple issues with this script. Ones that need immediate attention are:

1. There's an indentation error in the definition of `dessinerLigne` class.

Change:

```
class DessinerLigne:
def dessinerLigne(self):
    # Create a black image
    self.img=np.zeros((512,512,3),np.uint8)
```

to:

```
class DessinerLigne:
    def dessinerLigne(self):
        # Create a black image
        self.img=np.zeros((512,512,3),np.uint8)
```

and the indentation error should be fixed.

2. There's an incomplete line of code in line 32.
3. Is line 33 a part of the method `draw_circle()`? If so, it has be properly indented. Add 4 whitespaces in front of it.
4. You seem to have pasted the code from somewhere. During this process, it is very likely that some invisible control characters that might break the syntax may have arrived. Use an editor that has 'show invisible' features to resolve this issue.

Comment: went back over the documentation and rewrote the code entirely in note pad then copy and pasted it into the idle and got it to work. thanks for the reply man.

Comment: Great! Invisible characters can give you nightmares if you don't know about their presence.

Comment: i tried but it says my reputation is less then 15. but yes you are awesome and definitely helped